# Return another promise from a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have a promise for an object and would like to get a promise for a property of that object. How should I do that?

```
var user = Q.nfcall(User.findOne, {
    _id: userId
});
var accessToken = Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    user.then(function (user) {
        if (!user) return reject(new Error('User not found.'));
        if (!user.github.accessToken) return reject(new Error('Access token not found.'));
        return resolve(user.github.accessToken);
    }, function(err) {
        return reject(err);
    });
});
```

This is what I tried so far, but I'm not sure if its the best (or most correct) way.

Comment: Yes, this looks fine. Even ES6 Promises have similar structure only.

Comment: Why don't you chain `user` instead? `user.then(function() {}, function() {})`. You also may return a scalar value from the promise.

Comment: You are not returning `resolve`, so accessToken is `undefined`

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Updated! ^

Comment: I highly recommend reading the Promises/A+ specification. It isn't long, pretty understandable and applies to almost any promise library: https://promisesaplus.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)<sup>1</sup>! There's no need to use `Promise` constructor, `.then` already returns you a promise for the result of its callback:

```
var accessToken = user.then(function(user) {
    if (!user) throw new Error('User not found.');
    if (!user.github.accessToken) throw new Error('Access token not found.');
    return user.github.accessToken;
});
```

<sub>[1]: You've [seen yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29577341/revisions) how errorprone it is :-)</sub>

Comment: If later accessToken is not "used" or "called", will user be called?

Comment: @mushroom "promises" do not provide laziness.

Comment: @mushroom `user` is a promise. It cannot be called. If you mean `User.findOne`, *you* already did call it via `Q.nfcall` explicitly to create the promise.

Comment: @Bergi Ah yes, I was momentarily confused and should have thought more first. So `Q.nfcall()` immediately executes `User.findOne()` and returns a promise for `user`. It all makes sense now, thanks!